# Python Scraping: Trying to scrape a specific data (phone details) according to user input

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, user-input

I am doing web scraping from [www.gsmarena.com](http://www.gsmarena.com) . i want to extract a specific data according to the user input. this code returns all the phone models and names, i want to extract just the samsung phones details with a specific input suck as the RAM,ROM,CPU and COLOR. help me please.
thanks in advance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def link_scan(link_url):
    c = 1
    source_code=requests.get(link_url)
    plain_text=source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'brandmenu-v2 light l-box clearfix'}):
       for li in link.find_all('li'):
           for anc in li.find_all('a'):
               anc_src = r'http://www.gsmarena.com/' + anc.get('href')
               anc_name = anc.string
               print(c, anc_name,"\n", anc_src, "\n")
               c += 1
               inside_scan(anc_name, anc_src)


def inside_scan(name, hrefs):
    i = 1
    source_code=requests.get(hrefs)
    plain_text=source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'makers'}):
       for li in link.find_all('li'):
           for anc in li.find_all('a'):
               for nam in (sp.find('span') for sp in anc.find_all('strong')):
                   modal_name = nam.string
                   print("\t", i, "\t", name, modal_name)
                   i += 1

link_scan(r'http://www.gsmarena.com/')
```

Comment: Can you provide some scraping output you already have ?

Comment: It gave me all the phone's modals and names without specs:

1 Samsung
http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung-phones-9.php
   1 Samsung Galaxy Z Fold2 5G
   2 Samsung Galaxy Note20 Ultra 5G
  3 Samsung Galaxy Note20 Ultra
  4 Samsung Galaxy Note20 5G
  5 Samsung Galaxy Note20
  6 Samsung Galaxy Tab S7+
etc...
2 Apple
http://www.gsmarena.com/apple-phones-48.php 
  1 Apple iPhone SE (2020)
  2 Apple iPad Pro 12.9 (2020)
  3 Apple iPad Pro 11 (2020)
  4 Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max
  5 Apple iPhone 11 Pro
  6 Apple iPhone 11
  7 Apple iPad 10.2
etc...
3 Huawei
etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to play sometime with urls. In your case user may ask for a specific mobile phone manufacturer and target url would look like this:

```
https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung-phones-9.php
```

Moreover, you are quite lucky because you can fetch a certain cell phone details without redirecting to it's page. In your case each cell phone refers to anchor tag with a class name like this:

```
<a href="samsung_galaxy_m31s-10333.php">
```

It means you can parse links that start from "Samsung" in order to filter the query according to the user's needs:

```
https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung
```

To fetch CPU, RAM, e.t.c info you have to refer anchor tags:

```
<a href="samsung_galaxy_m31s-10333.php"><img src="https://fdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/samsung-galaxy-m31s.jpg" title="Samsung Galaxy M31s Android smartphone. Announced Jul 2020. Features 6.5″ Super AMOLED display, Exynos 9611 chipset, 6000 mAh battery, 128 GB storage, 8 GB RAM, Corning Gorilla Glass 3."><strong><span>Galaxy M31s</span></strong></a>
```